# Remove connman without disrupting ethernet connection

Tags: debian, apt, at, connman

For a bunch of historical and justifiable reasons, I have a situation where I need to programmatically configure a device with a fresh Debian installation, over a ssh connection. Think of it like a production line where the device arrives fresh and needs to be configured over the network via a script. One of the things I need to do as part of that configuration is remove `connman`.

If I do the most obvious thing and call `apt purge connman` from my script, it gets 20% the way through and the ssh connection is dropped. When I power cycle the computer and log back in, all is well, `connman` is gone and the network is configured the way I want.

The user experience though, is a little less than desirable. Here are some workarounds I thought of and why they haven't been satisfactory:

1. `echo` a warning from the configuration script that the purge process will halt, and that the user needs to wait a period of time and then power cycle the device.

   - Not only is that a poor user experience, it means this has to be the last thing the script does, and I can't check for error or report success.
2. Require the user to plug in a keyboard and monitor instead of using ssh.

   - Pretty neat fix, but might not always be practical.
3. Do something like `apt purge connman && reboot`.

   - Difficult to provide user feedback; ssh needs to be re-established (in a different way because part of the configuration changes the network and ssh settings); takes an unpredictable while.
4. Schedule the purge for sometime in the future.

   - Neither `at` or `crontab` have a `@before_reboot` equivalent and a `@reboot` or other arbitrary time might be too late, can't report success, and requires cleaning up after itself so it only fires once successfully.
5. Configure `connman` to do nothing, rather than deleting it.

   - Leaves a lingering doubt that it is indeed inert.

So is there a way to remove `connman` without killing the active ethernet connection? Can I prop up the connection until the next reboot, or just schedule the purge to be done during the next shutdown?

Comment: (5) doesn't seem to bad to me. Why do you have such a lingering doubt? Are there reported bugs where connman activated itself when configured to do so?

Comment: @muru only that I have close to zero experience with `connman`. So it would be a new exploration. The history is that this procedure was once applied to Raspbian Stretch on different hardware, and has many hours of proven in use confidence. We'd like to change as few things as possible this time around. This would be the only difference in userland software, which would be a pity, particularly given it provides no benefit.